# Cannot install deepspeech of python

Tags: python, pip, mozilla-deepspeech

I want to use DeepSpeech of Mozilla on my Linux 22.04 system, following this website:

```
https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/?badge=latest
```

At the very beginning line, at

```
pip3 install deepspeech
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech
```

I ran into internet and followed all methods such as upgrading pip3, using pip instead of pip3. I could not solve the problem.

This website:

```
https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3693
```

suggests to use archive. I did not understand which repository should I archive at this step.

It is very nice of you if you can help me.

Comment: Have you found the solution??? I am also stucked here...

Answer (score 6):

It appears that DeepSpeech is no longer maintained although there is no explicit message to users. However, both current and new users are continuing to submit pull requests and open issues with the assumption that the project is still actively being developed.

Check this link: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3693

Answer (score 2):

Got it working using a python3.7 virtualenv. It seems that python 3.7 is the last supported version for using deepspeech.

I'm in arch linux, so first I had to install python3.7 from the AUR:

```
yay -S python37
```

Then, inside my project folder, I created a venv:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 venv
```

After that, activate the venv:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Then, you can safely do

```
pip install deepspeech
```

Answer (score 1):

in 2021

https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech

became

https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT

as can be seen from the commit history, but is recommending

https://github.com/openai/whisper

Answer (score 0):

try this uninstall current python on your pc.
Then, install python version 3.7.3
and then again try pip install deepspeech.
This really works!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34863678)

Comment: Seems to answer it just fine.  Look at OP’s own answer.  Overeager criticism of a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I need to develop a transcriber tool using Python, so I did some research, and this was the result:

- DeepSpeech - No longer maintained
- Coqui - No longer actively maintained
- [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) - Actively maintained - Applies spelling corrections to the transcription
- [Vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk) - Actively maintained (uses [Kaldi](https://kaldi-asr.org) as core) - transcribe it in the same way it was spoken

I did a couple of tests and got great accuracy vs performance using both Whisper and Vosk. BTW, I noticed a slight difference in their transcription results. For example, I have an audio that the speaker says `I'm gonna get`, so Vosk transcribed it to `I'm gonna get`, and Whisper transcribed to `I am going to get`.